# node js "(10107) A System call has failed"

Tags: windows, node.js

I installed node in windows using node msi installer. everything was working, few days later, i run node in command prompt and i get the message as "socket: (10107) A system call has failed". I couldn't find any resources of what the issue or the fix is. any pointers?

resintalling node didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This link: 
[computeraid](http://computeraid.com.au/2011/08/08/error-10107-a-system-call-that-should-never-fail-has-failed/), helped

Run cmd as Admin

> netsh winsock reset

i didn't even had to restart and node started working right away. 
i guess problem was with windows sockets catalog, not node.

Comment: Worked for me as well :D